# Please Help me!! Would anyone can teach me IBAction how to use `isEqualToString` to an `NSArray` object from TableView only on cell?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Anyone can teach me IBAction how to use `isEqualToString` to an `NSArray` object from a TableView with one cell?

My first page is a TableViewController with 1 Cell and I have created NSSArray object to push the data to second page ViewController.

I created an `IBAction` to play a sound whenever user touch the button in ViewController.
(It means that When I click on button it loads a sound and according to the data of Cell from NSArray)

"DetailModal" is an `NSArray` object from other TableViewController.

I'm using AudioToolbox and I have created the sound file to soundID

How can I use `isEqualToString` to link the `NSArray` object?

For example:

I have created a list of soundID like this:

```
NSURL *buttonURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"A" ofType:@"m4a"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL1, &soundID1);

NSURL *buttonURL2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"I" ofType:@"m4a"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL2, &soundID2);
```

and

Detail2ViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *DetailModal;
```

How can I use "isEqualToString" to a NSArray object in IBAction?

```
- (IBAction)Sound {

    int sound =  _DetailModal;  (Don't know how to do. Want to equal a object _DetailModal but show error)

    if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"/a/"]) {    (_TitleLabel is a NSSArray object and equal to _DetailModal from another TableViewController)
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID1);
    }

    if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"/i/"]) {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID2);
    }
}
```

I have tried but fail...

I'm using storyboard

Thanks for advance! (I'm really beginner)

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you have problem in passing data from one controller to another controller i.e from tableviewcontroller to detailview in your case.

You can use following method in storyboard:

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

Please refer:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2

Comment: No. maybe you misunderstand my question I want the user touch the button will play the sound and it's according to TableCell data

Answer (score 0):

Modify your condition like that in `IBAction` for checking `isEqualToString` inside `NSArray`:-

```
for (NSString *str in _TitleLabel)
{
if([str isEqualToString:@"/a/"])
{
//Write your code
}
if ([str isEqualToString:@"/i/"]) 
{
//Write your code
}
}
```

Comment: Would you please teach me how to modify the (IBAction *sound to _DetailModal) Can I use like this:

- (IBAction)Sound:(UIButton *)sender {
    
    int sound =  _DetailModal;
    
    if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"/a/"]) {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID1);
}

Comment: TitleLabel is your array you cannot use like this